# What are the options for developer-unlocking a WP7 device?

Tags: 7.x, rooting

Short of signing up for the [developer program](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/) and paying $19, what are my options for unlocking my phone to allow loading arbitrary applications? The [ChevronWP7 program](http://www.chevronwp7.com/) shut down earlier this month, which was the only other option I was aware of (which was actually just using the developer program behind the scenes.)

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to do this that doesn't involve 1) spending money, 2) being a student, 3) owning a business?  Can't I just unlock my phone that I paid for with my money without all this ridiculous hassle?  What's the big deal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are a small business that is privately owned, produces software, has less than 1 million in revenue a year and you're not an employee of microsoft, you can apply for Bizspark. Bizspark will get you AppHub access.. which ultimately lets you unlock devices.

edit: 
I went and looked into my Bizspark account today, and the process of getting a token isnt there anymore. However, if you are accepted into the program you'll be assigned a local Bizspark associate. They might be able to get you a token, but this isnt a guaranteed process. Please "unanswer" this post. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a reference link for this? I cannot find anything on the Bizspark  website or the software spreadsheet. This answer seems to agree http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/308/295

Comment: You are right, the offer has been rescinded from the "offers" list. So, instead of automatically getting a token through an automated process, you can ask your handler (everyone gets a locally based Bizspark contact).

Answer (score 6):

If you're a student, you can get a developer unlock for free via [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=26), but this limits you to up to three sideloaded apps (vs the 10 from the paid unlock).

Answer (score 2):

[WP7RootTools](http://www.wp7roottools.com/) includes a way to set application as *trusted* meaning they will get full access to your WP7, be careful though as this is an easy way to brick your device if you don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [great guide](http://windowsphonehacker.com/articles/the_complete_guide_to_jailbreaking_windows_phone_7_and_7.5-09-24-11) to the various options available for unlocking depending on the device manufacturer. The below information is from the guide:

> Samsung 1st, 2nd generation: Interop Unlock possible with
>   [WindowBreak](http://windowsphonehacker.com/articles/developer_interop_unlock_your_samsung_wp7_with_windowbreak-12-23-11), version 7740 and below
>
> LG (all generations): Interop Unlock possible with [MFG
>   application](http://wiki.windowsphonehacker.com/wiki/Jailbreaking%3aLG)
>
> HTC 1st generation: Interop Unlock possible, see [Jailbreaking:HTC 1st
>   Generation](http://wiki.windowsphonehacker.com/wiki/Jailbreaking%3aHTC_1st_Generation)
>
> HTC 2nd generation: No interop, jailbreak, or custom ROMs possible yet
>
> Nokia: No interop/jailbreak yet

Comment: how does a person find out which generation his HTC device is?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the bizspark option still exists. I know they gave way 500 tokens last year but that offer isn't listed on the bizspark offers page anymore.

depending on which device you have, you might find guides for unlocking on XDA.

Comment: This answer would be better posted as a comment on the answer suggesting to use Bizspark.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have removed the ability to developer unlock Windows Phone 7 devices